# HidDevice.FromIdAsync returns null (Universal App)(Pi3)

Tags: c#, hid, universal

Trying to connect to a Makey Makey on a Pi3 running windows

```
        var dlist = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync();

        var output = "";
        foreach( var device in dlist)
        {
            output += $"Id:{device.Id}\r\n";
            output += $"Name:{device.Name}\r\n";
            output += $"Kind:{device.Kind}\r\n";
            output += "\r\n";
        }
```

Using that code I can find the device:
Id:\?\HID#VID_2A66&PID_0001&MI_00&Col01#7&2d913a22&0&0000#{884b96c3-56ef-11d1-bc8c-00a0c91405dd}
Name:Makey Makey v1.20aa
Kind:DeviceInterface

So can see the VID (2466) and PID (0001) 
Did a partial on **VID_2A66&PID_0001** so was able to get the HID wanted from list.

```
var foundDevice = dlist.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Id.Contains("VID_2A66&PID_0001"));
```

But now when I try and get the HID device.

```
var hidDevice = await HidDevice.FromIdAsync(DeviceId, Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
```

It always comes back with null.

I have tried putting the capability in appxmainfest

```
<DeviceCapability Name="humaninterfacedevice">
  <Device Id="vidpid:2A66 0001">
    <Function Type="usage:0001 *"/>
  </Device>
</DeviceCapability>
```

Even tried with using the device id of "any"

```
<DeviceCapability Name="humaninterfacedevice">
  <Device Id="any">
    <Function Type="usage:0001 *"/>
  </Device>
</DeviceCapability>
```

So any one have idea what have missed and why always getting a null object ?

Also if using the Hide Device Selector, how do we know the parameters to pass in ?

```
    ushort usagePage = 0x001;
    ushort usageId = 0x001;
    var ags = HidDevice.GetDeviceSelector(usagePage,usageId);
    var hidList = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(ags);
```

Where can we find a list of thse usageId, and what usagePage setting are.

Same question about the manifest,
How do we work out what to put for function type.

```
<Function Type="usage:0001 *"/>
```

Makey Makey is a Keyboard and Mouse input when used

Comment: Hello True Solutions, can you please share if you have found the solution? Thanks.

Comment: Yes the issue was that he makeey makey was a counter fit
So the driver worked fine when I get a real one.